# Turn On Faststart up In Dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

Hello I have a dualboot system with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 and the time of installing Ubuntu 20.04 I disabled fast startup in Windows to get rid of possible errors. But now I want to turn that feature **ON** because of slow Boot,slow shutdown and restart. So by some finding on Internet , I came to know that turning on that Windows feature ON in dualboot can cause data loss. So I do I enable that feature On without any data loss?

I can read and write Windows drive, did I have to change it to read only? and if so then how can I do that with GUI because terminal commands are confusing and wrong command can mess everything. Thankyou.

Comment: Dual boot do not use fast start.

Comment: But what about data loss? @David

Comment: What daat loss I just said DO NOT TURN FAST BOOT ON.

Comment: Windows Fast Startup is a form of hibernation. It means Windows does not relinquish control of the hardware and is not REALLY shut down. Use of Fast Startup is INCOMPATIBLE with the use of any other Operating System on that hardware, so sure you might lose data. Lots of it. Fundamentally, my-Windows-boots-slowly seems like a Windows support question which is off-topic here.

Comment: Yes its a little **off topic** sorry but I want a solution for slow boot and shutdows and I know its cause is dualboot, I asked the question on https://answers.microsoft.com/ but I didn't got a working answer I also increased virtual memory which is of no use but I tried it and the problem remains the same :( . But most of the users on this site have dualboot with Win and Ubuntu so I asked a question here to get a solution . Thankyou.@user535733

Comment: Hello I enabled fast startup in Windows and it solved my problem it booted in Windows in less than 30seconds!! while if I disabled fast startup it took 2min and 30 sec to boot but what about data loss? @David

Comment: I added a comment above what's your suggestion? @user535733